# Coredump while working on a function that reverses the string

Tags: c, string, reverse

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>

main()
{
    char tmpChar;
    char *str_1 = "Hello";

    int index;
    int len = strlen(str_1);
    for (int i = 0; i < len/2; i++)
    {
        index = len - 1- i;
        tmpChar = str_1[len - i -1];
        str_1[index] = str_1[i]; <<<<<--------------- core dumps at this point. Not sure why
        str_1[i] = tmpChar;
        printf("str_1[%d] = %c\n", i, str_1[i]);
    }
    str_1[len] = '\0';
    printf("str_1 = %s\n", str_1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ISO C99 standard has this to say about string literals (section 6.4.5/6):

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.

That's because, typically, all the string literals are lumped into a single area which may be marked read-only, and they're sometimes merged to save space. In other words, the two string literals:

```
char *p1 = "Googolplex";
char *p2 = "plex";
```

may be stored thus:

```
  +--- p1           p2 ---+
  |                       |
  V                       V
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| G | o | o | g | o | l | p | l | e | x | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
```

That means: don't try to modify them. It *may* work under certain situations but it's not something that you should rely on if you value portability even a little.

Change:

```
char *str_1 = "Hello";
```

to:

```
char str_1[] = "Hello";
```

since this is effectively the same as:

```
char str_1[6];
strcpy (str_1, "Hello");
```

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to modify the content of a string literal which invokes Undefined Behaviour. String literals are **generally** stored in read only section of memory and have static storage duration.

`char *str_1 = "Hello";`. In this case `"Hello"` is a string literal(stored in read only section) and you are trying to modify the content by doing this

```
str_1[index] = str_1[i];
```

Instead of making `str_1` a pointer to the literal [i.e. `char *str_1 = "Hello"`] make it an array of characters i.e. `char str_1[] = "Hello"`. The content of the literal would be copied onto the stack and you won't get any segfault if you try to modify the content then.

Comment: +1 since you nailed it, but strings are _not_ "stored in read only section", the standard has nothing to say on that, just that modifying them is undefined.

Comment: @paxdiablo : Yes you are right. The standard doesn't say anything regarding where string literals are stored but most implementations (that I know of) store them in the read only section. Added the word **generally**

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
char *str_1 = "Hello"; //read only
```

as

```
char str_1[] = "Hello";
```

Comment: This is correct. If you would have explained *why*, you would have gotten an upvote from me.